# How to insert the residual distribution of a linear regression, where the x axis is perpendicular to the fitted line?

Tags: r, data-visualization, linear-regression

I have seen some papers that deal (not completely) with residuals in a regression analysis in a smart way, they plot the residual distribution perpendicular to the fitted line. 
Example image from Figure 2 or 5 (linear regression) in: https://www.nature.com/articles/nn.4538#results

My R example:

The data example it has been taken from: https://www.r-bloggers.com/simple-linear-regression-2/

Data example:

```
alligator = data.frame(
  lnLength = c(3.87, 3.61, 4.33, 3.43, 3.81, 3.83, 3.46, 3.76,
               3.50, 3.58, 4.19, 3.78, 3.71, 3.73, 3.78),
  lnWeight = c(4.87, 3.93, 6.46, 3.33, 4.38, 4.70, 3.50, 4.50,
               3.58, 3.64, 5.90, 4.43, 4.38, 4.42, 4.25)
)
```

Linear regression model:

```
reg <- lm(alligator$lnWeight ~ alligator$lnLength)
```

Scatter plot:

```
plot(alligator,
   xlab = "Snout vent length (inches) on log scale",
   ylab = "Weight (pounds) on log scale",
   main = "Alligators in Central Florida"
)
```

Fitted line:

```
abline(reg,col = "black", lwd = 1)
```

Residual distribution (histogram):

```
hist(reg$residuals, 10, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
```

I would like to insert the histogram at the topright of the linear regression plot as the example image from Figure 2 or 5 (linear regression) in: https://www.nature.com/articles/nn.4538#results

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself yet to achieve this? If so, please explain what you tried and why it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: not sure how to do it in R but you can probably do it in Adobe Acrobat Pro. Its not uncommon for journal figures to use that technique for these kinds of adjustments

Answer (score 2):

This will work to get the residual histogram overlaid on the main plot. You'll have to do a bit of work to get it to be angled perpendicular, as in the examples you cite.

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_minimal())

alligator = data.frame(
  lnLength = c(3.87, 3.61, 4.33, 3.43, 3.81, 3.83, 3.46, 3.76,
               3.50, 3.58, 4.19, 3.78, 3.71, 3.73, 3.78),
  lnWeight = c(4.87, 3.93, 6.46, 3.33, 4.38, 4.70, 3.50, 4.50,
               3.58, 3.64, 5.90, 4.43, 4.38, 4.42, 4.25)
)

reg <- lm(alligator$lnWeight ~ alligator$lnLength)


# make main plot, with best fit line (set se=TRUE to get error ribbon)
main_plot <- ggplot(alligator, aes(x=lnLength, y=lnWeight)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,7))

# create another plot, histogram of the residuals 
added_plot <- ggplot(data.frame(resid=reg$residuals), aes(x=resid)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins=5) + 
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line.y=element_blank())

# turn the residual plot into a ggplotGrob() object 
added_plot_grob <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(added_plot)

# then add the residual plot to the main one as a custom annotation 
main_plot + annotation_custom(grob=added_plot_grob, 
                              xmin=4.0, xmax=4.35, ymin=1, ymax=5)
```

[image: scatterplot with fit line and overlaid residual histogram]

Then check out the docs for `ggplot2::` and `gridExtra::` to figure out the rotation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Possibly some useful code in https://github.com/mhenderson/funcgeo for rotation.

Comment: Also here: http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n3/zhou.pdf